# Alternative to <!--#include virtual="somefilename"-->

Tags: ssi

I have a website running an an old apache server with SSI enabled. My host wants to move to a new server which has SSI disabled for security reasons.

I have a whole lot of pages with Google Friendly urls which just have one line

```
<!--#include virtual="Url_Including_Search_String"-->
```

What is the best alternative to the SSI to keep my google friendly search strings returning the specified search result?

I can achieve most of the results with rewrite rules in the `.htaccess` file, however some search strings have a space in the keyword but the url doesn't. I can't do this with a rewrite rule

ie www.somedomain.com.au/SYDNEY.htm would have

```
<!--#include virtual="/search.php?keyword=SYDNEY&Submit=SEARCH"-->
```

However,the issue is 
www.somedomain.com.au/POTTSPOINT.htm would have

```
<!--#include virtual="/search.php?keyword=POTTS+POINT&Submit=SEARCH"-->
```

A rewrite rule cannot detect where a space should be in a Suburb name, so hoping there is an alternative for `<!--#include virtual=`

I have looked at `RewriteMap` but don't think I can access the file I would need to put this in.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Mod Rewrite to redirect any calls to non-existent files to your Search page.

For example:
`http://example.com/SYDNEY` redirects to

```
http://example.com/search.php?q=SYDNEY
```

(assuming there is not actually a /SYDNEY/ file at your server root.)

Then get rid of all those individual redirect pages.

As for the spaces, I'd modify my actual Search page to recognize (for example) "POTTSPOINT" and figure out that the space should be inserted.  Basically compare the search term against a database of substitutions.